# No packages in any requested group available to install or update on Centos 7 when installing XFCE

Tags: linux, vnc

I have a GCP instance running Centos 7 and am trying to follow the instructions [here](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-and-configure-vnc-on-centos-7/) to get vncserver running but I keep getting:

*Maybe run: yum groups mark install (see man yum)*
*No packages in any requested group available to install or update*

when running the command:

*sudo yum groupinstall xfce*

The output when I run *sudo yum group list* is:

Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, langpacks 
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile

- base: mirrors.advancedhosters.com
- epel: dl.fedoraproject.org
- extras: mirror.wdc1.us.leaseweb.net
- remi-php72: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
- remi-safe: mirror.pit.teraswitch.com
- updates: mirror.umd.edu
  Installed Environment Groups:
      Server with GUI
      GNOME Desktop
  Available Environment Groups:
      Minimal Install
      Compute Node
      Infrastructure Server
      File and Print Server
      Cinnamon Desktop
      MATE Desktop
      Basic Web Server
      Virtualization Host
      KDE Plasma Workspaces
      Development and Creative Workstation
  Installed Groups:
      Electronic Lab
      Graphical Administration Tools
      Legacy UNIX Compatibility
      Milkymist
      Security Tools
      System Administration Tools
      Xfce
  Available Groups:
      Cinnamon
      Compatibility Libraries
      Console Internet Tools
      Development Tools
      Educational Software
      Fedora Packager
      General Purpose Desktop
      Haskell
      LXQt Desktop
      MATE
      Scientific Support
      Smart Card Support
      System Management
      TurboGears application framework

I've tried the instructions [here](https://access.redhat.com/discussions/1262603) as well, but it still didn't work.  Any idea why I get this issue when it say Xfce is an installed group?